# How to make themed GoogleMap in android?

Tags: android, google-maps

How to make styled google map in android by changing colors of the map components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MapStyleOptions` for styling Google Map. 
More information in documentation:   https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/styling

Additionally Google provides wizard, where you can customize map.
https://mapstyle.withgoogle.com/

Answer (score 0):

With the reference to the Przemysław Piechota's answer,I developed a utility library to simplify the json creation(used for styling google map).Please check [ThemedGoogleMap](https://github.com/jineshfrancs/ThemedGoogleMap).